# A clarification about proof $\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a misunderstanding about the problem. (Complex analysis Elias M stein & Rami Shakarachi chapter 2 example 2).
Why $f(z)=\frac{-iz}{z^2}+E(z)$, I think f(z) is the derivative function but I get $\frac{-ie^{iz}z+2(-e^{iz}+1)}{z^3}$.

How they get $f(z)$ ?

Appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are right , so why $f(z)=\frac{-iz}{z^2}+E(z)$ ? why $\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} = \frac{-iz}{z^2}+E(z) $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(z) = \frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$ is defined at the beginning of the example.

To define $E$ we use the Taylor expansion of $e^z$ to write
$$e^z = 1 + z + z^2h(z)$$
where $h$ is analytic at $0$ (in fact, entire), so
$$f(z) = \frac{1-(1+iz+(iz)^2h(iz))}{z^2} = \frac{-iz}{z^2} + h(iz)$$
so $E(z)=h(iz)$ in particular is analytic at $0$.